# How to create a dynamic menu structure with Django?

Tags: django, menu

I want a menu structure with a menu and a submenu, and depending on
what page is currently viewed, I want to highlight items in both menus. Are
there any modules or apps that provide this? If not, what would be the best way
to approach the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Quick google search gives this:

http://code.google.com/p/django-treemenus/

http://code.google.com/p/django-menuse/

You can also create such simple menu manually, just pass to the template list of menu items, active menu and list of submenu items for the active menu and the active submenu item:

```
     <ul>
     {% for item in menu_items %}
         <li>
         {% if item.id == active_menu_item %}
             <span class="active-menu-item">{{ item }}</span>
             <ul>
                   {# Similar code for submenu items #}
             </ul>
         {% else %}
             <a class="inactive-menu-item" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item }}</a>
         {% endif %}
         </li>
     {% endfor %}
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [djangopackages](http://web.archive.org/web/20181007030357/https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/navigation/), the most popular menu application in 2018 is `django-sitetree`.

Item highlighting can be done with the second tool from the link above, [django-activeurl](https://github.com/hellysmile/django-activeurl).

For large sites, however, django-sitetree may have [performance](https://django-sitetree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/performance.html) issues.

There is another way which is related to the hierarchical structure of menus: `modified preorder tree traversal`, which optimizes database queries for tree lookups.

Use [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io) to store hierarchical data (such as menus with submenus to unlimited depth). Use [django-mptt-admin](https://mbraak.github.io/django-mptt-admin/) to easily manage them in admin menu. `contenttypes` framework may be useful for more generic menus (this is not shown in django-mptt tutorial).